# .htaccess code, is this example good coding practice?

Tags: .htaccess

Now that my feet are officially wet with .htaccess I have a new question. In one of the many tutorials I have bookmarked, the author recommends placing this bit of code at the beginning of the .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

I can understand the issues of avoiding parsing issues with that first line, so what I want to know is, aside from `RewriteEngine On` are the other two lines good practice or just adding bloat?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RewriteBase /` line is sometimes used to resolve relative URIs in the target and/or patterns of `RewriteRule`'s. For example, if an htaccess file is in the `/foo` directory, and you have rules that might look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/
RewriteRule ^bar$ index.php?bar [L]
```

Here, the rule's target `index.php?bar` is a relative URI and the *base* gets prepended to it, resulting in the URI: `/foo/index.php?bar`. When the rule's target is relative, apache will make a guess as to whether the URI is a file-path or a URL-path, and it doesn't always guess correctly. With the `RewriteBase /foo/`, apache knows that the `/foo/index.php` is a URL-path. There could be instances where the rewrite base doesn't match the folder that it's in, but the result is still the same. It acts as a URI base for the relative URI's that are in the rules.

Having it doesn't hurt, unless for some reason you want certain relative URI's to actually map to file-paths.

The **[`AddDefaultCharset`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset)** directive doesn't apply to the character set of the htaccess file, it's part of the response that the webserver gives to requests when the requested content is of type `text/html` or `text/plain`. Again, doesn't hurt to have this in your htaccess file unless you're text or html content is actually some *other* encoding (like *shift_jis* for example).

Comment: Many thanks again! All good info and I'm thinkin gthat this was a coding preference on behalf of the tutorial author. Excellent!